# Html ActionLink. Asigning items from list to Action Link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, actionlink

Im trying to create a menu, by creating ActionLinks with data i collected from database.
I tried with @item.name, @item.ActionName....but it doesn't work....
Im doing something wrong, but can't find what ....please help.
thanks

```
<ul id="menu">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.MenuList) 
    { 
        <li class="ajax_link">
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, item.ActionName, item.ControllerName)
        </li>
        <li>|</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast the ViewBag.  I assume you have a class called `MenuList` or something similar.  Change your code to this

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MenuList as List<HomeController.MenuList>)
{ 
  <li class="ajax_link">
     @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, item.ActionName, item.ControllerName)
  </li>
```

Or, ditch the annoying ViewBag altogether in favor of a viewModel and your original syntax will work as expected.
That is to say:

Make your list of menu items a viewModel property

```
public class MenuList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    //...
    public List<MenuList> MenuLists { get; set; }
}
```

Strongly type your view

```
 @model MvcApplicationForTestingStuff.Controllers.HomeController.ViewModel
```

and then your action link will work with this syntax

```
   <ul id="menu">
    @foreach (var item in Model.MenuLists) 
     { 
       <li class="ajax_link">
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, item.ActionName, item.ControllerName)
        </li>
        <li>|</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: @Aypeross what doesn't work? or more specifically, what DOES this achieve? Can you give us a view source?

Comment: @Aypeross Edited answer.  Maybe give it another shot